# Tkinter skips over part of the code detailing the reaction to an input - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am creating a program that judges the strength of passwords. Part of the code is supposed to check whether a password has any numbers. However, when I enter a password, it completely neglects the code detailing what to print as the output if there are no numbers, and instead returns with: 'this is too short.'

```
from tkinter import *

import re

def pass_Type():
  strength = pass_Type  #Applies pass_Type to the entire program

def value():
  value


def click():
    entered_text = entry.get()
    if entered_text in pass_Type:
        strength = pass_Type[entered_text]
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, strength)
         #Click function
    elif len(entered_text) < 9:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, 'This is too short')
    elif pass_Type and len(entered_text) < 9:
       output.delete(0.0, END)
       output.insert(END, strength)
    elif value(entered_text):                              }
        if not any(c.isdigit() for c in value):            }
          output.delete(0.0, END)                          }
          output.insert(END, 'Incorporate some numbers')   } #The problematic area
    elif value(entered_text) and len(entered_text)  < 9:   }
        if not any(c.isdigit() for c in value):            }
          output.delete(0.0, END)
          output.insert(END, 'Try to incorporate some numbers and increase the length of your password')
    else:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, "This password is acceptable!") #When the password is ok

Password = Tk()
Password.title('Password tester') 

label = Label(Password, text="Password:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)    #Entry label

entry = Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)     #Entry box

Button(Password, text='SUBMIT',width=5, command=click).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)  #Button

label = Label(Password, text='Strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)          #Output label

output = Text(Password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)                              #Output box 

pass_Type = {
  'Password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers',
  'password': 'This is a very predicatable password. You should incorporate numbers and capital letters',  #Common password glossary 
  '12345': 'Try and incorporate some letters',
  'qwerty': 'Try to jumble up your letters so the password is not so predictable.'
  }

Password.mainloop()
```

When I attempt to test the code by itself by entering over 9 characters, it rejects the code with the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "", line 25, in click
    elif value(entered_text):
TypeError: value() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

How can I make the program not skip over the aspect, and use the alternative output that I have programmed?
And if incorporating numbers was the only problem, how can I fix the error?

Comment: This elif value(entered_text): elif statement doesn't look like is going to do anything. Also you should avoid using built in functions as value() is built into python

Comment: I have updated my answer. I reworked your code a bit because there was some unnecessary stuff in it. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

Lets create a True/False variable and decide right off the bat if there is a number in the entry box.

If there is a number in the entry box then we can change that variable to True and the `elif` statement can pick that up.

There are a few ways to get this done but I chose to do it this way.

EDIT:

after looking over your code a bit I noticed sever things that were either not needed or redundant or did nothing at all.

Take this following code and it should produce the results you are looking for. Note the stuff I toke out. Of the following code as it really did nothing for you in the code.

UPDATE: Added a feature we talked about in chat.

```
from tkinter import *
import re

pass_Type = {
  'Password': 'This is a very predictable password. You should incorporate numbers',
  'password': 'This is a very predictable password. You should incorporate numbers and capital letters', 
  '12345': 'Try and incorporate some letters',
  'qwerty': 'Try to jumble up your letters so the password is not so predictable.'
  }

def click():
    entered_text = entry.get()
    x = False
    y = False
    for i in entered_text:
        if i in "0123456789":
            x = True
    for i in entered_text:
        if i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            y = True

    if entered_text in pass_Type:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, pass_Type[entered_text])

    elif len(entered_text) < 9:
        if x == True and y == True:
            output.delete(0.0, END)
            output.insert(END, 'This is too short')
        elif x == False and y == False:
            output.delete(0.0, END)
            output.insert(END, 'Try to incorporate some numbers, letters and increase the length of your password')
        elif x == False and y == True:
            output.delete(0.0, END)
            output.insert(END, 'Try to incorporate some numbers and increase the length of your password')
        else:
            output.delete(0.0, END)
            output.insert(END, 'Try to incorporate some letters and increase the length of your password')

    elif x == False:
        output.delete(0.0, END)                          
        output.insert(END, 'Incorporate some numbers')

    elif y == False:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, 'Incorporate some letters')

    else:
        output.delete(0.0, END)
        output.insert(END, "This password is acceptable!")

Password = Tk()
Password.title('Password tester')

label = Label(Password, text="Password:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(width=20, bg='light blue')
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

Button(Password, text='SUBMIT',width=5, command=click).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)

label = Label(Password, text='Strength:')
label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

output = Text(Password, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background='light blue')
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W) 



Password.mainloop()
```

I removed the following 2 function as they did literally nothing for you.

This function does nothing as no where in your code did you ever call that function. All you need to do is use pass_Type in place anywhere you had strength.

```
def pass_Type():
  strength = pass_Type  #Applies pass_Type to the entire program
```

This function also does nothing. even if you were to have code that calls this function `def value():` returns nothing and does not apply anything to a variable or widget.

```
def value():
  value
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, what I could use some help with an explanation is how you manged to allow the dictionary to overide 'len' (which is why I had def pass_type.)

Comment: @matt-333: I am not sure what you mean by override? All I am doing with `len` here is getting the count of how many characters long the string is from the entry widget.

Comment: 'def pass_Type' was used so that 'len' would not be the primary go to answer as 'this is too short,' and instead the go-to answer would be pass_Type.

Comment: The thing is @matt-333, your `def pass_Type()` was never used in the program. There was nothing in the program that called the function. It might as well have been a comment in the code. It just was not used in your code.

Comment: @matt-333: also there is no "overriding" going on. You can get the length of anything without change the variable being changed. When we call `len(some_variable)` all the program is doing is counting the number of characters in the string. It does not actually change some_variable.

Comment: @matt-333: I am glad you understand. I was not sure I was understanding what it was you were confused about. LoL. Well anyway, remember that a function does nothing unless you call `function_name()` somewhere in your program.

Comment: Can you use the number detector for letters?                                          y = False
    for i in entered_text:
        if i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYXYZ":
            y = True

Comment: @matt-333: Yes. You can use any string of text, numbers, and special characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146293/discussion-between-matt-333-and-sierra-mountain-tech).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function you defined:

```
def value():
   value
```

As the error message says it takes no positional arguments despite you passing them in from your condition(s).

Moreover, even if you fixhed that what is `value` it's not defined? At this point it's just referencing the function.

It looks like your trying to test whether there was simply any text entered in which case you can just directly test the "truthiness" of the string since a blank string `""` will equate to false.

Comment: The problem with entering a blank string is that another of my if statements clashes with it. ('Len')

Comment: Then fix the logic

Comment: What should I equal value to? If I take out my 'def value,' I will get the error that value is not defined.

Comment: Of course it's not defined you deleted the definition of value. That's what `def` signifies a *definition* of a function. I meant you should fix your logic to where your not trying to do that at all. It's unnecessary.

Comment: 'Fix your logic to where your not trying to do that at all' is not very specifc, please can you elaborate.

Comment: Using `value`.... You need to go through a Python tutorial. Your code is redundant in terms of repetition, the logic is poor, and needs (should) be restructured. Telling you how to fix it does nothing for you, because you won't be improving. Hacking away towards a solution isn't a solution.